# Multi Formatted TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to have the layout of the comments on a progam in the following form:

[image]

I want the USER_NAME in Bold, and the DATE in Enphasis (The red part should be normal, I don't want it red). My problem comes with the red part. I cant get the cooment to be displayed like this using layouts, I've been able to get:

[image] and [image]

Is there any way to get the comment working like the one I'm showing. I've thought about a multi formatted textView, is it posible??

If getting the comment like this is not possible, just say it's imposible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a WebView with loadData if HTML markup would be good, or alternatively delve into the realm of [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) text.

I've not worked with [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) text myself, but essentially it allows you to attach attributes (e.g. styles & colors) to parts of text in a TextView.

The relevant method is [TextView.setText(CharSequence text, TextView.BufferType type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) with BufferType of SPANNABLE. The documentation I've seen is.... confusing.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to put two `TextView`s into a `Linear` layout one after another and then use `SpannableStringBuilder` to assign the formatted text to the first view.

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append(text);
sb.setSpan(createBoldSpan(), 0, lengthOf(userName), 
           Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
firstTextView.setText(sb, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
```

`createBoldSpan` should return `TextAppearanceSpan`

```
private TextAppearanceSpan userNameSpanInBold(String userName) {
    return new TextAppearanceSpan(...);
}
```

please follow API docs for [`TextAppearanceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) - you can create one using custom style.